# Latest file name saving it a variable

Tags: shell, bash-scripting

I'm trying to save the latest file name to a variable and everytime I get permission denied error.
Any suggestions how to save it to a variable.

```
test = `$(ls -t /opt/inbound/Sample*.dat.gz  | head -1)`
```

Error:

-

```
bash: /opt/inbound/Sample_04142019_05_52_03.dat.gz: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either remove the backticks or the command substitution:

```
test=$(ls -t /opt/inbound/Sample*.dat.gz  | head -1)
```

or

```
test=`ls -t /opt/inbound/Sample*.dat.gz  | head -1`
```

See [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

By adding both, your code tries to execute the last filename it found

Answer (score 0):

Backticks and `$( … )` are [almost the same](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778/108618). You're doing something like

```
test = $( $(ls -t /opt/inbound/Sample*.dat.gz  | head -1) )
```

i.e. executing `ls … | head …` and then executing whatever it returns: `/opt/inbound/Sample_04142019_05_52_03.dat.gz` apparently. You don't want to execute this.

In addition you're about to execute `test`, not save anything to a variable. `test = whatever` runs `test` with arguments `=` and `whatever`. Proper variable assignment is without these spaces: `test=whatever`.

You probably meant

```
test="$(ls -t /opt/inbound/Sample*.dat.gz  | head -1)"
```

Note that [parsing `ls` is not recommended](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). There is no guarantee the variable will hold the exact and full name of the file you want. Even if you find a command that returns the exact name in all cases, names with trailing newline(s) won't be stored properly because `$( … )` deletes any trailing newlines.